# How to do an if statement that will return the word ”New” in column A if it beats the criteria in column F?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test
    Dim BR As Long
    BR = Range(“B” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range(“A4”).Formula =“=if(F4>datevalue(“3/29/2019”),”New”,””)”
    Range(“A4”).Copy
    Range(“A4:A” & BR).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End sub
```

I realize that the formula will not work because it ends the statement with the first parentheses but I can’t figure out how to do this formula in vba. If you could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Range("A4:A" & Br).Formula = "=IF(F4,DATEVALUE(""3/29/2019""),""New"","""")"`

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly